# What's the right way to do Octopus?

Tags: seafood, mistakes

On occasion I have bought sliced/chopped, pre-tenderized, frozen octopus from the local market and each time I attempt cooking it, it always is still a little chewy and smells like bay water. I suspect I'm not cleaning it right and boiling it too long but am unsure the right way to get a decent tasting octopus dish.

What is the best way to make a simply tasty octopus?

Comment: I expressed that it was pre-tenderized and this was not octopus but squid -- but thank you for referring me to a thread with answers.